# Can I use Node-Red to display one dashboard group per sensor?

Tags: iot, node-red, arduino-esp8266

I'm playing around With Node-Red (I'm still in the newbie stages)

I have around 20 ESP8266 modules taking temperature and humidity in various locations in and around my home.

The way I am doing it right now, is to put a webserver on each of my ESPs and have node-red poll them every 5 Seconds. This is ugly in all respects, as repeating this 20 times hurts the eyes. I've set up two of them already, and it looks bad:
[image: Setting up TWO sensors for Dashboard is already hard]

My question is:

Is there a way I can give node-red a list of the Devices (well, their IP addresses) and have node-red create my desired Dashboard for all of them? Looks like I would need a "for-each" module, as well as something to automatically create a group in the Dashboard for grouping the various gauges/Charts to each sensor.

Not a lot of code to share so far, but I did create a gist for you to see, if you're interested in the webserver part for ESP8266:

[Gist of how to Connect ESP8266 With Node-Red using Arduino/C](https://gist.github.com/digitaldias/3f3f617fb6273276b712fa990ecebf58)

In advance, thanks for your tips and suggestions

Comment: Have you considered running an mqtt broker on your central system, and make the ESPs push their data over mqtt to it - much more scalable than polling them because you just add more ESPs and they send their data without you midofiying the NR flow on the central system. NR can subscribe to mqtt topics to process the data.

Comment: Yeah, that will be my second Version, already trying to wrap my brains aroudn how MQTT Works, Reading up on that now. However, would that solve my issue With 20 Points of telemetry?

Comment: In the sense that you wouldn't have to code the polling of each one because the ESPs all push their own data to the broker, yes. You will have to give each ESP a unique ID, you might be able to use their wifi MAC address to do that automatically.

Comment: Ok, so the broker would act as a Field Gateway then, in front of NR? how do I go about splitting those up into unique Dashboard Groups? I haven't found any examples yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment you need to define each widget on the dashboard explicitly.

The closest you could do is use the template node and pass in an array of values that can be rendered in a loop, but that will not work for the Chart node or Text nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the Clear answer. Guess I'll move over to something else then, NR won't cover my scenario :)